# How to have a and/or system of equations?

Tags: spacing, equations, arrays

Something like this:

[image: system with or]

without too much stretching of the height of the system

I specifically want the word "or"/"and" to be inserted **between** the two lines (or more ?) of equation, using only `cases` is not a solution.

Comment: See the cases environment (amsmath package).

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you question correctly, than the following MWE gives what you after:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
  \left\{\begin{aligned}
      x &= 1 \\
      \text{or} \\
      y &= 1 \\
    \end{aligned}\right.
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Plain TeX macro `\cases` doesn't add a space at the right when the second column is omitted.

```
$$
  \cases{ x = 1       \cr
          \hfil\rm or \cr
          y = 1
  }
$$
\bye
```

Answer (score 0):

Update.

It turns out `cases`, suggested below, leaves a small space behind, at the right and a better solution is proposed based on `aligned` environment

[image]

A comparison with `cases`

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mleftright}
\begin{document}
\mleftright
\begin{equation}
  \left\{
    \begin{aligned}
      x &= 1 \\
      y &= 1 \\
    \end{aligned}
  \right.\tag{1}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

---

Usually, the `cases` environment is for this type of expressions

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{cases}
    x = 1 \\
    y = 1
  \end{cases}
\]

\end{document}
```

If you expect fractions and would like them to be typed in display style, use `dcases` instead

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[
 \begin{dcases}
   x = \frac{1}{2} \\
   y = 1
 \end{dcases}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Not really: `cases` will add unwanted space at the right.

Comment: @egreg Yup, it does add extra space. It truly comes with a surprise! Thanks.

Comment: `cases` must be used with additional material at the right explaining each cases.